# LINQ SQL join multiple n-to-n relations and filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, asp.net-core, join

I have the following tables:

```
Customer [idCustomer, ...]
Address [idAddress, ...
Customer_Address [idCustomer, idAddress, ...]
Customer_ShippingAddress [idCustomer, idAddress, ...]
```

In my Web Application (asp.net core 2.1 WebApp using razor pages) I want to filter customers by customer properties and also by address properties e.g. give me all customers where the name starts with "test" and where the zip starts with "10".

My problem is that I don't know how I would join the tables so that customers are kept where address match that are either in Customer_Address or in Customer_ShippingAddress.

My approach so far:

First filter only relevant customers:

```
IQueryable<Customer> customersFiltered = _context.Customer
.Where(c => c.Name.ToLower().Contains(CurrentNameSearchString.ToLower()) && 
            c.idCusomter.ToString().StartsWith(CurrentCustomerInternalNumberSearchString));
```

then I filter all relevant addresses:

```
IQueryable<Address> addressesFiltered = _context.Address
.Where(a => a.Street.ToLower().Contains(CurrentStreetSearchString.ToLower()) &&
            a.Country.ToLower().Contains(CurrentCountrySearchString.ToLower()) &&
            a.Zip.StartsWith(CurrentZipSearchString) &&
            a.City.ToLower().Contains(CurrentCitySearchString.ToLower()));
```

Now I want to join them so that I get a list of Customers that I can show on the frontend. I created a DTO for that:

```
public class CustomerIndexDTO{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int InternalNumber { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Addresses { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> ShippingAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

But I cannot figure out the join:

```
List<CustomerIndexDTO> Customers = (from c in customersFiltered
                /*join here*/      
                select new CustomerDTO
                {
                    Name = c.Name,
                    InternalNumber = c.idCusomter,
                    Addresses = c.CustomerAddress.Select(x => x.IdaddresseNavigation.ToString()).Distinct().ToList()
                    ShippingAddresses = c.CustomerShippingAddress.Select(x => x.IdaddresseNavigation.ToString()).Distinct().ToList()
                }).OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
```

I have a working solution where I can filter for customers and for 1 type of address but when I want to filter for both types of addresses the query just runs endless. Help highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `join` for this, since a Join changes the level of granularity of your query so you would have more than one item returned for each customer. There are other approaches that would probably work better. Here's one:

```
from c in customersFiltered
where c.CustomerAddress.Any(ca => addressedFiltered.Any(af => af.IdAddress == ca.IdAddress))
    || c.CustomerShippingAddress.Any(csa => addressedFiltered.Any(af => af.IdAddress == csa.IdAddress))
select new CustomerDTO
...
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked and is such a nice and clean solution.